# which conversion is right in C++?

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I want to covert a void* to char* reinterpret_cast and static_cast, which one is fit for ?`static_cast<char*> or reinterpret_cast<char*>`

Comment: Honestly if you're dealing with `void*` you can just use C-style casting. `char* something = (char*)myvoidptr;` C++ casting doesn't give you any benefit in this scenario even in terms of maintainability.

Comment: @tenfour On contrary, it is easier to grep, then c-style cast

Comment: @tenfour c-style casting is verboten on many projects precisely because c++ style casts are easy to find while c-style casts are very hard to find.

Comment: @tenfour: for another benefit of `static_cast`: `(char*)myconstvoidptr` will remove const, `static_cast<char*>(myconstvoidptr)` won't. Obviously if you don't want to remove const then it's a programmer error to cast it away with a C-style cast, but one purpose of the different C++ casts is to help catch errors like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's largely a question of style.  `static_cast` can do any conversion
which is the opposite of an implicit conversion (and which doesn't
remove `const` or `volatile`).  Since `char*` to `void*` is implicit,
`static_cast` would seem indicated; the usual rule is to use
`static_cast` in preference to `reinterpret_cast` whenever possible.

Given that this use is particularly dangerous, some coding guidelines
might prefer `reinterpret_cast`, to signal this fact.

Comment: +1, but I don't know about it being a question of style. Since `reinterpret_cast` allows a superset of `static_cast`, I would consider `static_cast` safer and therefore always preferable.

Comment: In the case of converting from `void*`, `static_cast` is no safer than is `reinterpret_cast`. I much prefer seeing a `reinterpret_cast` rather than a `static_cast` for such conversions precisely because that reinterpret cast is screaming "Danger, Will Robinson! Danger!"

Comment: @DavidHammen I sort of agree with you.  But the choice isn't dictated by the language, so I call it a question of style.

Comment: @JamesKanze I wasn't disagreeing. The other way around; I completely agree that preferring `reinterpret_cast` over `static_cast` (or vice versa) for converting from `void*` is purely a matter of style. Both casts will work here, and both will do exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

`static_cast` (together with `dynamic_cast`) is for casting between objects in the same class hierarchy, while `reinterpret_cast` is to cast between different types completely. So in your case you should go for `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: That's a scary over-simplification of `static_cast`.

Comment: I'd rather say that `static_cast` is for *converting values*, while `reinterpret_cast` is for mangling the type system.

Comment: @KerrekSB `static_cast` can also be used within an inheritance hierarchy, and for converting to and from `void*`.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Within an inheritance hierarchy I would claim that you are *converting* pointer values, since pointers to related classes are mutually convertible (sometimes even implicitly so). That's not subverting the type system. I didn't realize you can static-cast *from* void pointer, though. Good to know!

Comment: @JamesKanze: Coming to think of it, the very definition of `void*` suggests that a *conversion* to and from any pointer type should be possible, so `static_cast` is actually even better.

Comment: @KerrekSB Formally, any time you're converting pointers, you're converting pointer values.  Even `void*` to `int*` can change the value.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Yes, of course, which is why I now prefer to use `static_cast`.

Comment: Even though `static_cast` works when converting from `void*` to any non-const, non-volatile pointer type, I much prefer `reinterpret_cast` for such conversions. Static cast is no safer than reinterpret cast for such conversions. If the thing disguised as a `void*` wasn't a `Foo*` to begin with, casting to `Foo*` *by any means* yields unspecified results. Those `void*` pointers tend to come from legacy systems or systems written by C± (rather than C++) programmers. I like seeing such interfaces easily searchable via `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: I dispute the relevance of, "`static_cast` is for casting between objects in the same type hierarchy". One thing that `static_cast` is for, is for *reversing implicit conversions*, and this is such a case, as are downcasts of pointers in a hierarchy. `static_cast` is also for converting between numeric types, which are not in the same hierarchy. It's also for calling explicit conversion operators, in or out of a hierarchy. So the fact that `char` and `void` aren't in the same hierarchy is not sufficient to rule out the use of `static_cast`.

Comment: @David: in that case I'd prefer to define a function template like `<template T> T *recover_userdata(void*)`. If you're highlighting that the reason such casts occur is interaction with C-style callback APIs, might as well make it explicit rather than attaching your own meaning to `reinterpret_cast`. The template definition can contain a `reinterpret_cast` if you insist :-)

Comment: @Steve: That is exactly what I do for such C style /  C± style conversions from `void*`. I write a template whose use signals intent, but whose implementation is just a `reinterpret_cast`.

Answer (score 3):

`reinterpret_cast` between pointer types is defined in terms of `static_cast` through `void *`:

> #### 5.2.10 Reinterpret cast [expr.reinterpret.cast]
>
> 7 - [...] When a prvalue
>   `v` of type “pointer to `T1`” is converted to the type “pointer to *cv* `T2`”, the result is `static_cast<cv
>   T2*>(static_cast<cv void*>(v))` if both `T1` and `T2` are *standard-layout* types and the alignment
>   requirements of `T2` are no stricter than those of `T1`, or if either type is `void`.

So if you're converting between standard-layout object pointer types (e.g. `char *`) via `void *`, then `static_cast` is appropriate for the conversion to/from `void *`.

Answer (score 1):

`reinterpret_cast` works for you in this case, but do not make a using it often a common practice, since it's the most dangerous cast. Basically, you can `reinterpret_cast` totally unrelated pointers, so it's your obligation to take care of the result (i.e. checking if the result is valid for further usage).

Comment: @tenfour, why do you have to take it literally... I meant that it can cast totally unrelated pointers, and result in a very dangerous behavior if you don't know what you are doing. The only thing it guarantees is that if you cast `A` to something, and then cast the result back, you will get a valid object.

Answer (score -1):

I guess it depends on context: 
    static_cast<> 
should be used in case when there is implicit conversion.
    reinterpret_cast<>
should be used when both pointers are of different types

Though reinterpret_cast is not recommended.

You shouldn't use static_cast for casting down an inheritance hierarchy, but rather dynamic_cast.

From
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0w9f63b(v=vs.80).aspx

**The reinterpret_cast operator can be used for conversions such as char* to int*, or One_class* to Unrelated_class*, which are inherently unsafe.**

Comment: If they are the same type why would you cast at all? In what way does this answer the question?